# Hang applications when pasting from terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome, gnome3, gnome-terminal

I am encountering a very weird bug. *Sometimes*, when I copy contents from the terminal and paste them elsewhere (e.g. in a text editor, in a browser tab) it hangs that application or browser tab. I try pasting in multiple applications to eliminate the hypothesis that it is a applicaiton-specific bug.

Sometimes the process needs to be killed, some times it would become responsive again after a minute or two.

The weird thing is, if I go brew a coffee and then come back, and try to copy the exact same piece of text again, and paste it, it may work again.

So it's not something I can reproduce consistently, but this happens to me several times a day.

Here're my specs:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 4.13.0-31-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 19 16:34:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.26.2

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
```

If anyone has any idea of how to go about debug it, or has any idea of why this happens, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I have this often when the selection I made is rather big.  Did happen on Debian and now on Devuan too.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille : Are you using Debian 9 Stable ? I don't have such problems on Debian 8 though.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille my selection is very small. I would understand why it would hang if the selection is large, but nope.